# Charts X Value seems to shift to the right

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I've got a problem with Windows Charts:
I'm using Fastpoint and when plotting a LOT of points (100000+) at X=0,Y=0, they seem to shift towards positive X values. (to the right)

```
for (int k = 0; k < amountofpoints; k+=1)
{
    newGraph.Series[item.name].Points.AddXY(0,0)
}
```

Comment: So you want to plot 100000+ points at the same point (0,0) but upon using the above code they end up being plotted towards positive values like (1,0) or (2,0) etc. Right?

Comment: Did you set a xaxis.Maximum?

Comment: Mikaal Anwar:
Yes, even though I use 0,0 as input parameters.

Taw:
I did yes. It is tending towards positive values. I made 1 area, which is called newarea and added this to the same Chart.

Comment: Indeed it does both for FastPoint and for Point. Arguably the mistake is to pile all points onto the same spot.. It will not happen if even one point is added to a different spot! You can also add a dummy series with an invisible (transparent) dummy point. Bte: The number of points doesn't matter; it happens even for 10 points.

Comment: TaW Would it help to make a check for the location so that if it already exists it does not place the point?

Comment: Yes, that would be another workaround and, given the numbers you want to deal with advisable as well.  (((Btw, did you see the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32182781/display-circle-in-chart-with-radius-in-chart-units-c-sharp/50427848#50427848) I posted to you? Just in case you still want a circle on the chart)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like a minor bug in MSChart.

It  happens when all visible points are located at the same position.

Unfortunately even a `RecalculateAxesScale();`on the ChartArea doesn't help.

It happens even for small numbers of points and gets worse when adding more..:

[image]

The only workaround I see is to have at least one point at a different position so that the layout calculations span a non-zero distance.

You can hide the point by making it transparent or you can place it in a different series in the same chartarea, it just needs to be considered for calculating the display.

I called it a 'minor' bug because the whole setup makes obviously no real sense.

So instead of working around you should consider avoiding the situation by not adding all those identical points in the first place..

Comment: Thanks for the well explained and animated answer. I will try add the new point/ try to check points and not add them when they are the same as previous.